# How to scroll down two images in the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have this HTML code in which I want to display two images in parallel. It should work like a change slider image with scroll option:

The problem is that I can't scroll down into the div with class `.image-comparison-slider`.

```css
#image-comparison-slider {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--image-comparison-slider-width);
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: -7px 5px 16px 1px rgba(56, 86, 122, 0.6);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

#image-comparison-slider img {
  display: block;
  width: var(--image-comparison-slider-width);
  height: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-comparison-slider">
  <img class="overflow-auto" width="100%" src="../../static/img/screenshot.png" alt="before">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img width="100%" alt="after" src="../../static/img/screenshot1.png" />
  </div>
  <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
  <span class="label label-after">After</span>
  <div class="handle">
    <div class="handle-line"></div>
    <div class="handle-circle">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="handle-line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The js code related to the problem is here :

```js
 const slider = document.querySelector("#image-comparison-slider");
 const sliderImgWrapper = document.querySelector("#image-comparison-slider .img-wrapper");
 const sliderHandle = document.querySelector("#image-comparison-slider .handle");

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", sliderMouseMove);
slider.addEventListener("touchmove", sliderMouseMove);

function sliderMouseMove(event) {
   if(isSliderLocked) return;
       const sliderLeftX = slider.offsetLeft;
       const sliderWidth = slider.clientWidth;
       const sliderHandleWidth = sliderHandle.clientWidth;
       let mouseX = (event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX) - sliderLeftX;
       if(mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
          else if(mouseX > sliderWidth) mouseX = sliderWidth;

          sliderImgWrapper.style.width = `${((1 - mouseX/sliderWidth) * 100).toFixed(4)}%`;
          sliderHandle.style.left = `calc(${((mouseX/sliderWidth) * 100).toFixed(4)}% - ${sliderHandleWidth/2}px)`;
        }

        let isSliderLocked = false;

        slider.addEventListener("mousedown", sliderMouseDown);
        slider.addEventListener("touchstart", sliderMouseDown);
        slider.addEventListener("mouseup", sliderMouseUp);
        slider.addEventListener("touchend", sliderMouseUp);
        slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", sliderMouseLeave);

        function sliderMouseDown(event) {
          if(isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = false;
          sliderMouseMove(event);
        }

        function sliderMouseUp() {
          if(!isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = true;
        }

        function sliderMouseLeave() {
          if(isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = false;
        }
```

Here are some functions that helps me to move the slider above the images to be able to see the differences between them.
It works properly but I need to scroll in the parent div and I can't do that.

Comment: If this is a js problem, you'll need to show the js too

Comment: I updated the question with js code.